# Image on onBindViewHolder won't stay on Recyler View after reopening the app (using Picasso)

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, picasso

After I add profileimage on the recycler view it shows on the Recyler View along with its respective profile name, but after reopening or terminating the app, the loaded image is replaced with the placeholder like the image won't stay after reopening.  This is my code on my onBindViewHolder:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHodler holder, int position, @NonNull AddStudent model) {

        holder.sName.setText(model.studentFullname);
        holder.sEmail.setText(model.studentEmail);
        holder.sAge.setText(model.studentAge);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(model.studentImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.defprofile)
            .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
            .into(holder.imgStudent);
}
```

But in my edit dialog, if open it, the profile stays but the problem is the recyler view onbindviewholder, it doesn't stay.

Model Class:

```
package com.example.attendancechecker_application;

public class AddStudent {
    public String studentFullname, studentEmail, studentAge, studentImage;

    public AddStudent(){

    }

    public AddStudent(String studentFullname, String studentEmail, String studentAge, String studentImage){ //String getPassword
        this.studentFullname = studentFullname;
        this.studentEmail = studentEmail;
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
        this.studentImage = studentImage;


    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like, your `model.studentImage` gets null or something. Can you add a log in `onBindViewHolder` and share it here... So, I can see what's happening. and Kindly attach your model class within your question.

Comment: Log.d("MyTag", String.valueOf(model.studentImage)); before Picasso.

Comment: Yeah thanks I could try that, the thing is that this picasso works after I add the image, also it works even if i press back and explore the app.  But If I reopen the app the recyler view picture disappears

Comment: model class already added

Comment: I get it,, I want to see your log when you reopen, so we can detect the problem. thanks, now the log plz

Comment: I've added the log but the result is the same

Comment: 2022-12-22 15:06:59.619 4409-4409/com.example.attendancechecker_application D/MyTag: content://media/external_primary/images/media/23859

Comment: I've tried adding image and the logcat shows the exactly the same when i reopen the app after adding images but the difference is the image wont show after reopening it even though the logcat says otherwise

Comment: Oh damn, I think I should use the uri.string instead of this one

Comment: Damn I knew it! HAHAHH it's all good man thank you